# Handle the debugger detaching in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

In accordance with the [Debugger DevTools API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger#event-breakpointResolved), there is no debugger detach event. Can I catch the event for detaching the debugger when the user clicking "cancel" e.g.?

Sample code for attach:

```
chrome.debugger.attach(
    {
        tabId: tabId
    },
    '1.3',
    () => {
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
            {
                tabId: tabId
            },
            'Debugger.enable',
            {},
            result => {
                // ...
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't get the question. [`chrome.debugger.onDetach` is a thing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#event-onDetach). How is it not what you want?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're talking about debugger _feature_ within the devtools disabling.

Comment: @Xan No, I am talking about detaching debugger that was attached by chrome.debugger.attach, not the debugger feature. That is exactly what I looking for! Please post the answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to catch your debugger connection being closed (as opposed to an event happening within that connection), there is a [`chrome.debugger.onDetach` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger#event-onDetach) provided by the API.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround that suits me: `setInterval` with try/catch some debugger command.

```
const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        // await send 'Debugger.setBreakpointsActive' with active=true
    } catch (error) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        onDetach();
    }
}, 500);
```